# App Not working, Unfortunately, XML has stopped error

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling

I have written this code to parse this xml:

http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2

But when I run it... it say "APP Stopped Working" and I can't figure out the reason... Please help!

The code is:

**xmlActivity.java**

```
package com.example.xml;

public class XmlActivity extends ListActivity {
    static final String URL = "http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SeriesRecord = "SeriesRecord"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_latitude = "latitude";
    static final String KEY_longitude = "longitude";
    static final String KEY_location = "location";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SeriesRecord);

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_SeriesRecord, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SeriesRecord));
            map.put(KEY_latitude, parser.getValue(e, KEY_latitude));
            map.put(KEY_longitude, parser.getValue(e, KEY_longitude));
            map.put(KEY_location, parser.getValue(e, KEY_location));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_latitude, KEY_longitude,
                        KEY_location }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.desciption,
                        R.id.cost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_latitude, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_longitude, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_location, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SingleMenuItemActivity.java**

```
package com.example.xml;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends Activity {

    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_latitude = "latitude";
    static final String KEY_longitude = "longitude";
    static final String KEY_location = "location ";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get XML values from previous intent
        String latitude = in.getStringExtra(KEY_latitude);
        String longitude = in.getStringExtra(KEY_longitude);
        String location = in.getStringExtra(KEY_location);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);

        lblName.setText(latitude);
        lblCost.setText(longitude);
        lblDesc.setText(location);
    }
}
```

**xmlParser.java**

```
package com.example.xml;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * 
     * @param url
     *            string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * 
     * @param XML
     *            string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     * 
     * @param elem
     *            element
     */
    public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     * 
     * @param Element
     *            node
     * @param key
     *            string
     * */
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the `Logcat` output for your error: exception stack trace etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do slow operation like HttpRequest in the Activity Thread. You must put them in a separate thread (AsyncTask). This is mentionned by Google but i lost source i'm sorry.

You should try creating an AsyncTask here is how you should try :

```
public class GetSoigneurInfoTask extends AsyncTask<Document, Integer, Document>                 //Le même code s'applique pour presque tout sauf onPostExecute()
{
    Document doc;
    String xml;
    String url;

    public GetSoigneurInfoTask(String URL)
    {
        url = URL;
    }

    protected Document doInBackground(Document...params)
    {
        xml = XmlFunctions.getXML(url);                                                         
        doc = XmlFunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        return doc;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document result)
    {
            if(result != null)
        {
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("RootTag");                                //Crée une liste avec les elements sous soigneur
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                {
                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nodelist = element.getElementsByTagName("childTag");
                    Element element1 = (Element) nodelist.item(0);
                    NodeList fstNm = element1.getChildNodes();
                    soignTemp = fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So you call your methods in `doInBackground()` and you do everything you have to do with UI in `onPostExecute()`!

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am not able to get what do you mean "You cannot do slow operation like HttpRequest in the Activity Thread"

i was doing this operation on another URL and it was working fine and is still working but not on this url

Comment: here i found the [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html)

Comment: When i try to open your URL in a browser it says : Missing parameter: xmin.

Comment: http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx?op=GetSeriesCatalogForBox2

yeah this is the link

Comment: Can you really get information from that? XML file should look like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml). I mean they show a lot of examples but these aren't parseable i believe. Correct me if i'm wrong!